# guard evaluation in Python vs C++

Tags: python, c++

Just in recent times I went through one of my code (in Python) in which **guard evaluation** was badly missed. I shortened my code to make it a brief one

```
>>> x = 4
>>> y = 0
>>> x >= 1 and (x/y) > 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#16>", line 1, in <module>
    x >= 2 and (x/y) > 2
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

here we need to add guard

```
>>> x >= 1 and y != 0 and (x/y) > 2 # y!=0 is a guard
False
```

Now I have two questions:

1. I believe similar kind of scenario could have been best caught with
   **C++**, as it compiles the code and will produce a warning at first. Let
   me know if I am wrong here?
2. Other question is that we use `py_compile.compile('file_name')` and it
   just verifies syntax. Don't we have any module in Python that can catch
   these kind of misses?

Comment: That would require solving the halting problem: `x / (programHalts(some_program) ? 1 : 0)`

Comment: A C++ compiler will not catch this either, as you could easily have found out.

Comment: The tool you may be looking for is something lint-like. For python you have `pylint`. This is a possible fault that a compiler might not catch (it normally only catches cases where the denominator is known to be zero).

Comment: But there is a builtin guard in Python already, it raises an exception! Or, how about you add other guards that assure that the types of `x` and `y` are compatible scalars? No, cluttering the code with error handling rarely works well: It is of itself error prone and hides the actual logic from the view of the reader.

Comment: @skyking : pylint seems useful. And it also provide basic info on whole code. I guess you should have written the same as an answer instead of comment. Anyways i solved my query, thanks :)

Comment: @Shrey That was just a point in a direction, I've actually not used `pylint`. That's why I didn't post it as an answer. Now you're probably more qualified to post an answer yourself.

Comment: @skyking hmm I posted what i analyzed so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since python is a loosely typed language, thus it become difficult(impossible i believe) to analyze the code for the variable types. We can use `pep8` or `pylint` to analyze the code. They can only inform us about the indenting and code writing as per `PEP`.

For below file *guard_eval.py*

```
sherry@Sherry-Linux:~$ cat guard_eval.py 
x=6
y=0
if x >= 1 and (x/y) > 2:
        print True
else:
        print False

sherry@Sherry-Linux:~$ pep8 guard_eval.py 
guard_eval.py:1:2: E225 missing whitespace around operator
guard_eval.py:2:2: E225 missing whitespace around operator
guard_eval.py:4:1: W191 indentation contains tabs
guard_eval.py:6:1: W191 indentation contains tabs
```

pylint provides code ratings as well :)

But in case of C++ we can modify the compiler to `analyze code with the variable type` and hint user to have guard expression for `integer/integer division` while compiling.